# I cannot deploy firebase cloud functions: Failed to load function definition from source, No "exports" main defined in D:\

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to implement Firebase Storage into my Cloud Functions app script. I've been running into a problem where my code won't deploy at this point in the script:

```
const app = express();
app.engine('hbs',engines.handlebars);
app.set('views','./views');
app.set('view engine','hbs');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

I run into this error:

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\Documents\ShowtapeLibraryAdmin\node_modules\firebase\package.json

I am using Firebase 9.14, Functions 4.1.0, and Google-Cloud/Storage 6.70 as well as Firebase/app 0.8.4.

I've tried updating firebase, checking the code from the [tutorial I used for cloud functions](https://towardsdatascience.com/host-a-dynamic-website-on-google-firebase-for-free-using-node-js-and-cloud-firestore-db-88e98239e1b9) as well as updating any other packages and NPM

Here is the full index.js: https://pastebin.com/Q8J0LzCh

*I do apologise if I have not properly formatted this question correctly, this is my first Stack Exchange post!*

Comment: I have not verified that tutorial but it is three years old. That can be ancient in the cloud world. Perhaps try a current tutorial.

Comment: Hi. The tutorial worked previously, ever since I added storage function it has  suddenly broken. However, I believe the storage function code I wrote has nothing to do with the error I'm getting. The function had worked previously (I already tested it, and I got an output in Firestore).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Q8J0LzCh <-- Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase uses a [modular](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade), functional syntax starting from version `V9.0.0`. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase/app');
```

---

It seems you are trying to use Firebase SDK in a Cloud Function so you should ideally use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) itself and not the client SDK as well. Try updating to latest version of Firebase Admin SDK and refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getStorage } = require('firebase-admin/storage');

const storage = getStorage();
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) for Firebase Admin for Cloud Storage for more information.